# Get all lines from console within same application

Tags: c#

I have an application that writes all sorts of status update and times to the console. I also have an email function that emails to clients. I would like at the end of the application send an email with all lines from the console (same application).

There does not seem to be a function Console.ReadAllLines.

I saw some ideas with GetStdHandle but could get it to work.

Any ideas how I could do this in c# pls?

Comment: When you write to the console, why not write each line to an array at the same time, and then dump the array into the e-mail?

Comment: You could simply refactor your methods to store them in a `List<string>` before they write the line to the console. @Tim: an array has a fixed size.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Good point.  Just woke up so I'm not thinking clearly yet :)

Comment: I'm interested in this question as well. Ideally this can be done without having to manually store the values. Thus we can just use `Console.WriteLine(format, args)`, etc.

Comment: thanks. I know I could store it in a list of strings but I only add the feature now and I dont really want to go back to all places where I write to console, which in this case I would have to. In my case these are just maybe twenty places but it could be hundreds in theory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by implementing your own `TextWriter` and `Console.SetOut`

```
public class MyWriter : TextWriter
{
    private List<string> lines = new List<string>();

    private TextWriter original;
    public MyWriter(TextWriter original)
    {
        this.original = original;
    }
    public override Encoding Encoding
    {
        get { return Encoding.Default; }
    }
    public override void WriteLine(string value)
    {
        lines.Add(value);
        original.WriteLine(value);
    }
    //You need to override other methods also

    public string[] GetLines()
    {
        return lines.ToArray();
    }
}
```

And use it like this

```
var writer = new MyWriter(Console.Out);
Console.SetOut(writer);
Console.WriteLine("Hello world");
Console.WriteLine("Bye!");
var lines = writer.GetLines();
```

Comment: But this means that values are no longer written to the console window, right?

Comment: @ZongZhengLi `original.WriteLine(value);` Makes sure that it is written in Console. I tested it and working fine.

Comment: This is neat, but then as you said, "You need to override other methods also", just like the other answers...

Comment: @ZongZhengLi Yes, If you use only `WriteLine(String)` then this is enough :)

Comment: thanks. Maybe this is a stupid question but do you need to overwrite all methods or just the once you intend to use?

Comment: That depends upon what are the overloads of `WriteLine` you use

Comment: Greate Example, but all what you need to override is `Write(char value)` method. Every Write/WriteLine method finish there, so you really don't need to override them all. Just see the original code [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/textwriter.cs,14783d0a26561fe9)

Answer (score 2):

Reading information back that's already been output to the console is a backwards design.  Instead, store the information away in a DB/File/Memory so it can be re-used.  continue to display the output as you do.  However, when you need to send an email dig the info out of the DB/File/Memory.

It could be done like:

```
List<string> outputList = new List<string>();
string output = GetOutput();//Run continuously...perhaps in a loop or event trigger..whatever applies
outputList.Add(output);
Console.Writeline(output);

//when ready
SendEmail(outputList);
```

Comment: I think if it were possible to do this cleanly it would be good design. What if I'm making a lightweight console application that has the option of dumping the output when the user requests it?

Comment: Have you looking into a component like Log4Net? It's meant to be light, non-intrusive and very flexible. You could setup a logger to the console and anything else you need, and enable / disable each one separately through runtime configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a wrapper class to take care of it easily.

```
public class ConsoleWriter()
{
    public static List<string> AllLines = new List<string>();

    public static WriteConsole(string text)
    {
        AllLines.Add(text);
        Console.Write(text);
    }
}
```

Then read AllLines when you want to send the mail.

Comment: Unfortunately this would require implementing the ~15 overrides of `Console.WriteLine` just to get all the functionality for that method. Also it is not thread safe, but I suppose that is easy to fix.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Oh, why? Seems like the simplest way to write it.

Comment: But it won't be that simple if you have used other overloads of `Console.WriteLine` like `WriteLine(char[] buffer, int index, int count)` or `WriteLine(string format, params object[] arg)` altough they are pretty easy to handle too.